# How to get unique records on the basis of one property using Crieteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I want Unique records on the basis of a single property value using Crieteria, kindly tell me what will be the way to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
            criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("yourProperty")));
            List result = criteria.list();
```

Or, if you want the entire row you can use detachedCriteria:

```
            DetachedCriteria dt = DetachedCriteria.forClass(yourClass.class);
            dt.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("yourProperty")));

            criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("yourProperty", dt));
            criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Pojo.class);
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("property")));
List list = criteria.list();
```